# Need to create image ISO from USB stick, possible?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, usb, virtualbox, iso-image

I'm trying to install windows 10 on Virtualbox, which is on a Ubuntu 18.04 OS, and I have a bootable USB with windows on it.

For some reason VB is not recognizing my USB so looks like I have to get a copy of Windows 10 iso to do this, and I don't have a physical CD.

Anyway I want to ask, but you can't create an iso from my USB drive, right, from Ubuntu OS? Searching around seems like imgburn does the trick but it is an .exe file.

Comment: If the USB stick is the problem, creating an ISO from the stick seems like a wasted effort.  You should either figure out the reason your VM cannot boot from the stick, or just download the ISO, directly from Microsoft and use that instead.  **ImgBurn is a horrible program.**  Any event, it's not clear, what your actual question is.

Comment: ImgBurn is horrible and many links for it are full of malware. Yes, as suggested above, the best way to install a VM is from an ISO. I'm not sure if a USB can be used because we can only pass USB devices to a VM (in virtualbox) when a VM is already running.

Comment: Try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/240810/479613), which uses the basic `dd` disc copy program to create the image. Note that if the disc is much bigger than the stored files use you can use the `count=` option in order to stop the ISO from being needlessly large. I also always use `conv=sync` with `dd`; otherwise, any read error will make the target file system completely unreadable from that point. You shouldn't need a physical DVD: you ought to be able to set the ISO as a virtual DVD. I can't verify this as I have difficulty getting `vbox` to run in 18.04, but it works in VMware.